# programmatically creating a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Initially I used the IB to drag a navcontroller onto my tabbar and then setting the root controller. However, I'm trying to create a nav controller without IB.

What I've done is created a navcontroller subclass that will be used in my tabbar. The nav bar does show up so I know that is working.

Now, I need to push a viewcontroller into the hierarchy. In the nav controller's viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    InfoViewController *initialController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:initialController animated:YES];

    [initialController release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I get no errors, but nothing shows up in the navigation controller. Anyone know why?

Comment: Apple is recommending not to subclass UINavigationController BTW...just an FYI, not recommended. Also, why not just push your view controller to the nav controller, and then present it modally? the easiest way really...

Comment: if you shouldnt subclass the navcontroller how else would you do it programmatically? You have to use the nib? Arent I pushing my viewcontroller to the navcontroller?

Comment: saw you find the problem..let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

What does your InfoViewController's init method look like? If you're using a nib to build that, then you need to call initWithNib, not init.

Comment: no nibs involved. I think i found the problem. I was using self.navigationController in the navigationcontroller. It should be self

Answer (score 0):

Create the viewcontroller when/where you create the navigation controller (and add them to it) then add the list of view controllers to the tabbar.